# Auto-save on change in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

I am looking for a Notepad++ plug-in that automatically save a document whenever a change is made on it in Notepad++, or as a last resort when Notepad++ loses focus. It should work on Windows. Ideally it should be easy to turn on and off the plug-in.

I need this because I edit a bash script on Windows and run it in a Linux vm through shared folder. I would like to avoid having to hit ctrl+s each time I want to run the script after a modification.

Comment: Related: [Any way to have Notepad++ automatically save on exit?](http://superuser.com/questions/844381/any-way-to-have-notepad-automatically-save-on-exit) says *there is one to auto save open documents […] It's called AutoSave and is available to download [here](https://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins)* Btw: first hit on a [Google search for "notepad++ autosave"](https://www.google.de/search?q=notepadd%2B%2B+autosave) ;) Quote the linked site: *allows to automatically save the currently open files based on a timer schedule (default is 1 min)*, so it's not *exactly* what you asked.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, looks like it only saves every 1 minute though :/ "The plugin mentioned only allows option to save in minute intervals. (i.e. autosaving every 1min is most frequent will do) "

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote: not *exactly* what you're looking for, but pretty close (possibly as close as you can get). Hence (and since I've not used it myself) a comment, not an answer :) So if there is no answer to your request, you've at least got a "work-around".

Comment: @Izzy Sounds good :)

Comment: You may want to look Autohotkey. I didnt tried the scenario you asked and currently have no time to test it, but this program is very capable and i am almost sure it can be done. You may need to make some research and try error though

Comment: What's the use case? Fear of crashing? In my experience, when my PC crashes, I reopen Notepad++ and all files are up to date, including new files which I had never saved.

Comment: @Mawg I edit a bash script on Windows and run it in a Linux vm through shared folder. I would like to avoid having to hit ctrl+s each time I want to run the script after a modification.

Answer (score 3):

There are two strongly related question in the SE network, which are slightly outdated:

- [is there an autosave function/plugin for notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18656899/1548472) from StackOverflow SE
- [Any way to have Notepad++ automatically save on exit](https://superuser.com/q/844381/431462) from SuperUser SE

These answers lists two autosave plugins (which are easily found in [Notepad++ Plugin Central](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#A)):

- **[Autosave2](http://www.scout-soft.com/autosave/)
  by www.scout-soft.com** — Autosaves by creating a copy of the file at given time interval. In this particular context not so useful
- **[Autosave](//sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins) by Franco Stellari** — Option available to configure autosave on timed intervals *or when notepad++ looses focus*

Picture displaying the new option dialog window (from version v1.20 
2010-07-16) regarding autosave on loss of focus (see first option):

[image: Picture from fstellaris displaying option window of plugin]

This new functionality of *Autosave by Franco Stellari* regarding autosave on loss of focus, should handle your usercase just fine.